# Kotlin variables that are not in scope?

Tags: kotlin

On https://github.com/mozilla/rust-android-gradle/blob/8183f9e927336011c7c09d75efd4f5f411940db1/plugin/src/main/kotlin/com/nishtahir/CargoBuildTask.kt#L19 we have this kotlin code:

```
open class CargoBuildTask : DefaultTask() {
    var toolchain: Toolchain? = null


    @Suppress("unused")
    @TaskAction
    fun build() = with(project) {
        extensions[CargoExtension::class].apply {
```

I'm very confused as from where does `extensions` come from, as well as `project`. They aren't local variables, they aren't in a scope or something. What are they?

Answer (score 3):

**Inheritance** is the answer to `project`.

```
CargoBuildTask : DefaultTask()
```

Do you see how `CargoBuildTask` inherits properties of `DefaultTask`?
**Thus** `project` is a property from `DefaultTask`. However, `extensions` is a property from `project` which is of Type `Project`.

[Read this documentation on `DefaultTask` and you will have more understanding.](https://docs.gradle.org/4.10/javadoc/org/gradle/api/DefaultTask.html)

**Kotlin's `with`** is the answer to `extensions`.

In short, with `with` you can invoke methods without explicitly stating its subject. ([Read more here](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/with.html))

For example, these two code snippets mean the exact same thing:

```
    with("string") {
        substring(3) //invoke method without subject
    }

    "string".substring(3) //Same as above
```

Here is the method from `org.gradle.api.Project`

```
   ExtensionContainer getExtensions();
```

**Now**, If you are wondering how Java's `getExtensions()` turned into Kotlin's `extensions`, [read this](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-interop.html#getters-and-setters). Basically states that traditional `Getters and Setters` in Java are interpreted as `Properties` in Kotlin.

**PS**: If you are unsure of what `Inheritance` is in OOP/Kotlin, [read this](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/inheritance.html).

Comment: Not extension though, `extensions` comes from `project` as the receiver of the `with` and its a property of `project`, not `DefaultTask`.

Answer (score 1):

1. The `project`comes from the `DefaultTask()` inherited in the current class. Inheritance is used here which is a very basic concept. Read more about Kotlin's inheritance [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/inheritance.html).
2. The `extensions` comes from `project` using `with` which is one of the scope functions.

   Read more about with [here](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/with.html).
   [image].

   For example. Suppose you've a Data class.

   ```
   data class PersonModel(val name: String, var age: Int)
   ```

   And you create a model of it as

   ```
   val personModel = PersonModel("Adam", 30)
   ```

   Now, if you pass it to a with function as a reciever, you can access 'personModel`'s properties directly in the with's scope as:

   ```
   with(personModel) {
       //name is the property of personModel
       val nameWas = name
       //Declared var and can be editable.
       age = 31
   }
   ```

   `with` works with functions as well where you can pass a function as a reciever to it and it returns the returned value of the function.

   These scope functions (`let`, `run`, `with`, `apply`, `also`) are extremely useful in production environment.